# How to add legend information for the meaning of points added to a boxplot in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I consider the following type of grouped boxplot where a point is added for each group with some additional information (here the variance). How can I add in the legend information/annotation that says that the triangles denote the variance?

The aspired result is a legend that first distinguishes the boxplot groups "g2" (red is 0, blue is 1; this is now already in the plot) and then has an extra row/section denoting triangle symbols as the group specific variances (this is missing and needed).

```
library(ggplot2)
n=1000
dat = data.frame(    g1 = as.factor(rbinom(n,1,0.5)), 
                     g2 = as.factor(rbinom(n,1,0.5)))
dat$x = rnorm(n, as.numeric(dat$g1)+ as.numeric(dat$g2) , as.numeric(dat$g1) + as.numeric(dat$g2))
dat.var = aggregate(x ~ g1 + g2, data = dat, var)

ggplot(dat,aes(x=g1, y=x, fill=g2)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0.5)    +
  geom_point(data = dat.var, aes(x=g1, y=x, group=g2), pch=17, col="black",
             position=position_dodge(width=0.75), size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use labs function

You can use `scale_shape_manual` function and remove redundant `aes` mappings like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = g1, y = x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = g2), outlier.size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(
    data = dat.var,
    aes(group = g2, pch = 'variance'),
    col = "black",
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
    size = 3
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('variance' = 17), name = 'Vars')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me. Now in the plot "g2" has been replaced by "Variance", but this is not true. "g2" is still needed to distinguish the boxplot groups. I need an extra row that says something like "triangle symbol: Variance".

Comment: I added this to my question to make it clearer, sorry for possible confusion.

Comment: yes, super! but why is there now a point in the boxplot legend (beneath g2)? Actually, best would be no point at all in that part of the legend

Comment: The points are due to the shape the boxplot's outliers are depicted with. I am not sure whether they can be suppressed in the legend without suppressing them in the plot as well.

Comment: @tomka The problem was due to `mapping`. We need to add `aes(fill = g2)` only for `geom_boxplot`, not for all graphs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```r
library(ggplot2)
n=1000
dat = data.frame(    g1 = as.factor(rbinom(n,1,0.5)), 
                     g2 = as.factor(rbinom(n,1,0.5)))
dat$x = rnorm(n, as.numeric(dat$g1)+ as.numeric(dat$g2) , as.numeric(dat$g1) + as.numeric(dat$g2))
dat.var = aggregate(x ~ g1 + g2, data = dat, var)

ggplot(dat,aes(x=g1, y=x, fill=g2)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0.5)    +
  geom_point(data = dat.var, aes(x=g1, y=x, group=g2,pch = 'variance'), col="black",
             position=position_dodge(width=0.75), size = 3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('variance' = 17), name = ' ')
```

[image]

The `pch = 'variance'`-part in the point-layer sets the name, the `scale_shape_manual` sets the desired shape and the `name = ' '`-part removes the (duplicated) 'variance'-title.